# IAR assembler BKPT immediate as input operand

Tags: c, breakpoints, inline-assembly, iar

I am writing a flashloader for a Cortex M4 device and I'd like to "return" a value for the driving PC application using the breakpoint instruction's immediate value.

While hardcoding an immediate works fine:

```
__asm("bkpt 0x70");
__asm("bkpt %0" : : "i" (0x70));
```

as soon as I want to "return" something run-time dependent like

```
uint8_t status = Flash_EraseAll();
__asm("bkpt %0" : : "i" (status));
```

The compilation fails with

> Error[Ta090]: Immediate operand is not constant

I tried using preprocessor macros with different concatenate setups, but to no avail.

Has anybody got an idea of how I could input the run-time dependent status flags to the `__asm()` block in IAR as an immediate? Based on what I read [here](http://supp.iar.com/FilesPublic/UPDINFO/007448/ew/doc/infocenter/iccavr32.ENU.html), this is not exactly possible, but there might be a clever hacky way to do it.

P.S.: Yes, as a workaround I could use a switch statement where I list and hardcode every possible state, but that's just ugly and long.

Comment: Your solution is unsafe as you modify `sp` in first ASM statement. The push, breakpoint and restoration of `sp` must be in the same asm statement.

Comment: @TimothyBaldwin It might explain a couple of weird behaviours I'm getting. Before I modify my Edit, can you please elaborate how this is exactly unsafe? What could happen to the device/stack the works case? I must add that the __("bkpt 0x0"); is the last statement of my code

Comment: Post your answer as an answer, where people can vote on it.  Don't give it special status by editing it into the *question*.  If it's better than the (half-assed) existing answer, you can accept your own answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the hint, I modified the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [@Devolus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2282011/devolus)'s idea, I ended up with the following:

```
    uint32_t status = Flash_EraseAll();
    __asm volatile ("str %0, [sp, #-4]!\n\t"   // Push to stack
                    "bkpt 0x0\n\t"             // Halt CPU
                    "add sp, sp, #4\n\t"       // Restore SP
                    : : "r"(status));          // status as input to __asm()
```

The assembly instructions tells the compiler to put the status variable to a convenient register "r", and store that register's content under the stack pointer's pre-decremented address, then halt the CPU's execution with an immediate 0.

The driving application would poll the target if it was halted (bkpt hit). If halted, by reading the 16-bit data under the current PC (__asm("bkpt 0x00") -> 0xbe00 -> #imm = 0xbe00 & 0x00ff = 0), the application can make sure that the execution had stopped at the right place. It then would read the 32-bit data under the final SP address to fetch the status of the embedded code's execution.

This way, instead of a static 8-bit code from the bkpt's immediate, one can "report" more stuff to the outside world dynamically (32-bit in this case).

As [@PeterCordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes) highlights, the push and bkpt statements must be in the same inline assembly instruction, otherwise the compiler might decide to insert code between the statements. Also, the SP must be restored to the value before the __asm() as the compiler assumes sole control over SP.

Comment: You don't mention restoring `SP` anywhere.  With this asm, the breakpoint handler needs to add `4` to SP before resuming, otherwise the inline asm has modified SP without telling the compiler.

Comment: @PeterCordes That was the end of my program so I didn't need to restore anything. I guess if somebody wants to do anything else after resuming the execution from the bkpt, they can just add a "add sp, sp, #4" to undo what the str did?

Comment: Yes.  This is a pretty key detail to leave out for any future readers that might find this useful.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the help, truly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I would push the value on the stack, and then use the `bkpt` instruction with a defined number, so the debugger can look at the stack for this state.

Something like this (pseudocode):

```
__asm("push %0" : : "i" (status));
__asm("bkpt %0" : : "i" (0x70));
```

Of course you shouldn't forget to cleanup the stack afterwards.

Since `bkpt` is encoded with an immediate only, you can obviously not change that at runtime, as you would have to modify the code.

Comment: Hm... This is not a bad idea and seems simple enough. Didn't think of it. I'll wait for a while to see if anybody has additional thoughts to it. Thanks!

Comment: Both instructions need to be part of one asm statement, otherwise the compiler could decide to put some compiler-generated instructions between those statements.  Also, presumably you need to clean up the stack after resuming.  (ping @davidanderle).  Also, obviously you need a constraint other than `"i"` for `status`, because `"i"` requires a compile time constant to substitute as an immediate.  Probably you want `"r"(status)`, and you can just hard-code `bkpt 0x70` again unless you want to set the number with a C macro definition.